# How to stop the playbook if one play fails

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook with 3 plays. When one of the plays fail, the next plays still execute. I think it is because I run those plays with a different host target.

I would like to avoid this and have the playbook stop when one play fails, is it possible?

```
---
- name: create the EC2 instances
  hosts: localhost
  any_errors_fatal: yes
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - ...

- name: configure instances
  hosts: appserver
  any_errors_fatal: yes
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
   - ...

- name: Add to load balancer
  hosts: localhost
  any_errors_fatal: yes
  vars:
    component: travelmatrix
  tasks:
    - ...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use any_errors_fatal which stops the play if there are any errors.

---

```
- name: create the EC2 instances
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  any_errors_fatal: true
  tasks:
   - ...
```

[Reference Link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#aborting-on-the-first-error-any-errors-fatal)

Comment: This does not work because `any_errors_fatal` marks only the hosts in the play as failed, but the next play applies to a different host (it actually applies to localhost). I have updated the playbook in the question to show that `any_error_fatals` is already set.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not test properly. Your answer is right. SO does not let me remove the -1 at the moment but I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Can this be set globally using some command line param?

Answer (score -2):

it is ansible bug
to workaround use `max_fail_percentage: 0`

Comment: It doesn't work. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16666